# Nginx + uWSGI + django NoModuleFoundError: No module named 'saleor'

Tags: python-3.x, nginx, uwsgi, django-deployment

Python 3.6.8 to create venv
uwsgi installed in venv and is properly symlinked and using the correct python version
nginx installed system wide

just trying to get the most basic `uwsgi --ini myinifile.ini` to function properly.

Despite days of trying to fix this problem I always end back up here, with my django application not being recognized by uwsgi when I launch it.

uwsgi works properly when `uwsgi --uwsgi-file test.py --http-socket :8001`

I can `python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8001` just fine and django launches the application with 0 permission issues on navigating the application website.

I've seen this error so many times I think I'm taking crazy pills and missing something silly and obvious.

```
[uWSGI] getting INI configuration from /home/saleor/saleor/saleor/wsgi/uwsgi.ini
[uwsgi-static] added mapping for /static => /app/static
*** Starting uWSGI 2.0.18 (64bit) on [Mon Nov 18 07:36:36 2019] ***
compiled with version: 7.4.0 on 18 November 2019 04:47:07
os: Linux-4.15.0 #1 SMP Thu Aug 23 19:33:51 MSK 2018
nodename: myurl.com
machine: x86_64
clock source: unix
pcre jit disabled
detected number of CPU cores: 2
current working directory: /home/saleor/saleor/venv/bin
detected binary path: /home/saleor/saleor/venv/bin/uwsgi
chdir() to /home/saleor/saleor/saleor
your processes number limit is 62987
your memory page size is 4096 bytes
detected max file descriptor number: 1024
building mime-types dictionary from file /etc/mime.types...554 entry found
lock engine: pthread robust mutexes
thunder lock: disabled (you can enable it with --thunder-lock)
uwsgi socket 0 bound to TCP address :8001 fd 3
Python version: 3.6.8 (default, Oct  7 2019, 12:59:55)  [GCC 8.3.0]
PEP 405 virtualenv detected: /home/saleor/saleor/venv
Set PythonHome to /home/saleor/saleor/venv
*** Python threads support is disabled. You can enable it with --enable-threads ***
Python main interpreter initialized at 0x558314cc3dd0
your server socket listen backlog is limited to 100 connections
your mercy for graceful operations on workers is 60 seconds
mapped 145808 bytes (142 KB) for 1 cores
*** Operational MODE: single process ***
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'saleor'
unable to load app 0 (mountpoint='') (callable not found or import error)
*** no app loaded. going in full dynamic mode ***
*** uWSGI is running in multiple interpreter mode ***
spawned uWSGI master process (pid: 7969)
spawned uWSGI worker 1 (pid: 7970, cores: 1)
^CSIGINT/SIGQUIT received...killing workers...
worker 1 buried after 1 seconds
goodbye to uWSGI.
```

This is my uwsgi.py file named:`__init__.py`

```
"""WSGI config for saleor project.
This module contains the WSGI application used by Django's development server
and any production WSGI deployments. It should expose a module-level variable
named ``application``. Django's ``runserver`` and ``runfcgi`` commands discover
this application via the ``WSGI_APPLICATION`` setting.
Usually you will have the standard Django WSGI application here, but it also
might make sense to replace the whole Django WSGI application with a custom one
that later delegates to the Django one. For example, you could introduce WSGI
middleware here, or combine a Django application with an application of another
framework.
"""

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

from saleor.wsgi.health_check import health_check

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "saleor.settings")

# This application object is used by any WSGI server configured to use this
# file. This includes Django's development server, if the WSGI_APPLICATION
# setting points here.

application = get_wsgi_application()

# Apply WSGI middleware here.
# from helloworld.wsgi import HelloWorldApplication
# application = HelloWorldApplication(application)

application = health_check(application, "/health/")
```

And this is my uwsgi.ini

```
[uwsgi]
die-on-term = true
http-socket = :$(PORT)
log-format = UWSGI uwsgi "%(method) %(uri) %(proto)" %(status) %(size) %(msecs)ms [PID:%(pid):Worker-%(wid)] [RSS:%(rssM)MB]
master = true
max-requests = 100
memory-report = true
module = saleor.wsgi:application
processes = 1
static-map = /static=/app/static
mimefile = /etc/mime.types
env = /home/saelor/saleor/venv
virtualenv = /home/saleor/saleor/venv
chdir = /home/saleor/saleor/saleor
master = true
vacuum = true
chmod-socket = 666
uid = saleor
gid = saleor
```

I'm just trying to get uwsgi to run my saleor app so I can start to work on getting it and nginx to communicate properly :( I'm lost and my brain seriously hurts.

Answer (score 2):

1. update to python 3.8
2. install uwsgi inside your venv
3. uwsgi --http :8000 --module saleor.wsgi

do not touch any other settings

Answer (score 1):

I have got this error and I solved it this way

1. Install uwsgi inside your venv
2. If it is already installed, then deactivate your virtual
   environment, then again activate it.

3.uwsgi --http :8000 --module saleor.wsgi